# Installing tns-android failed

Tags: android, nativescript

I have a problem when trying to create a NativeScript App. I ran through the setup-tutorial for windows on the NativeScript side and created a "HelloWorld" via

`tns create HelloWorld --template nativescript-template-tutorial`

Response:

`-- nativescript-template-tutorial@3.1.0
  +-- nativescript-theme-core@1.0.4
    -- tns-core-modules@3.1.0
      -- tns-core-modules-widgets@3.1.0`

`npm ERR! registry error parsing json`

-- tns-template-hello-world@3.1.0

Project HelloWorld was successfully created.` %path_to_my_Application_/HelloWorld
 -- tns-template-hello-world@3.1.0

Project HelloWorld was successfully created.

when i navigate into "HelloWorld"-Folder and try "tns run android" the Emulator opens and the following Message(s) display:

Searching for devices...
Starting Android emulator with image Nexus4
Waiting for emulator device initialization....

iTunes is not installed. Install it on your system and run this command again.

Copying template files...
  \ Installing tns-androidInstalling  tns-android
Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: Error: Command npm.cmd install tns-android@3.1.1 --silent --save-exact --save failed with exit code 1.

I already tried reinstalling but that didn't work. I tried reinstalling nativescript and running the "tns install android" command -> What i got was the following error:

Refusing to install  as a dependency of itself.
There are two spaces between "install" and "as a dependency", i was thinking if something might be missing there? The exact same thing happens when i go for "tns platform add android".

The Message says "install iTunes" but since that should be an Android App running on an Android Emulator i do not know why iTunes should be connected with it? Perhaps someone might explain that to me.

Edit:

npm -v says "3.10.10"

tns info says that nativescript and tns-core-modules are up to date, but Android seems to be "not installed". Sadly i can't figure out, what causes the error and what to do against it.

Comment: Delete the platforms and node_modules directories if they are present. Do a `npm cache clean`, make sure there is no `tns-android` package in the `dependencies` of your package.json and try again, if that fails you could try starting up a new project with `tns project create myNewApp`, see if that helps.

Comment: creating another App does not work - sadly. When i try npm info, i get errors:                         
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "info"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! Invalid package.json
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!    %Path_to_my_app%\npm-debug.log

Comment: Also npm cache clean did not work, getting the following error:

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir '...\Roaming\npm-cache'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir '...\Roaming\npm-cache'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rmdir',
npm ERR!   path: '...\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

I am already running it as Administrator

Comment: npm quirks... restart the system and retry?

Comment: I did, now he seems to have problems with my npm proxy.. For whatever reason, i did not change anything with the settings